# How To Connect A Azure Sql Server 2012 Database From Localmachine

Tags: sql-server, azure, sql-server-2012

I want to connect my **SQL server management studio** which is running locally with a **Azure SQL Server 2012 database**

Now i have enable the sa account on the SQL server side and i also check the server name by running this query --

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME
```

I got the output

```
MSRV01\SQLSERVER
```

Now from my local machine when i am trying to loginto that Azure SQL server like this --
[image]

It retun this error

[image]

Do any one have any idea what i am doing wrong here !

Comment: Check the answer from chris. If your SQL server is hosted elsewhere, the you need to provide the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your local machine is on the same domain (or even subnet) as the azure VM then accessing via machine hostname will never work.

If you are using an Azure hosted database (i.e. not a VM) then in your [Management Portal](https://portal.azure.com), navigate to the database settings panel. At the top will be listed the `Server name` with a URL like `xxxxxxxx.database.windows.net`. Use this to connect to your database in SSMS.

Further reading: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-database-connect-query-ssms/